# django rest framework serializer.save() inernal error

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

When I try to create a user I get 500 internal error when `serializer.save()` method is called. It worked fine yesterday and after a good sleep it stopped working.

```
class UserCreate(APIView):

    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            if user:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_304_NOT_MODIFIED)
```

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField(
        required=True, validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )
    username = serializers.CharField(
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())]
    )
    password = serializers.CharField(min_length=8)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            validated_data["username"],
            validated_data["password"],
            validated_data["email"],
            cellphone=validated_data["cellphone"],
            sex=validated_data["sex"],
            first_name=validated_data["first_name"],
            last_name=validated_data["last_name"],
            profile_image=validated_data["profile_image"],
        )

        return user

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "username",
            "password",
            "email",
            "cellphone",
            "sex",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "profile_image",
        )
```

Comment: do you have the stack trace available? If yes, then just append it to your question. That would help in understanding the problem.

Comment: You might also need to call `user.set_password(validated_data["password"])` function. This will store the hash encrypted of your password.

Comment: it does not throw any errors, and I have tried to `try : except: ` and it prints `profile_image`. Why doesnt it throw the error?